# Unable to implicitly convert type cross solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, visual-studio-2015

Hi everyone I am new to programming, I am currently trying to create a web service to retrieve the customer information in my database but currently I am unable to solve this error, someone please help me

CustAccounts.svc.cs

```
public class CustAcc : ICustAccounts
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<CustAcc> GetCustAccJSON()

        {
            List<CustomerAccountDAL> abc = new List<CustomerAccountDAL>();
            CustomerAccountDAL caDAL = new CustomerAccountDAL();
            List<CustAcc> allAcc = new List<CustAcc>();
            allAcc = caDAL.retrieveCustAccount();

            //caDAL.retrieveCustAccount();
            return allAcc;
        }
    }
```

CustomerAccountDAL.cs

```
public List<CustAcc> retrieveCustAccount()
        {
            List<CustAcc> acc = new List<CustAcc>();
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                string jString = "Select * from CustDB";
                SqlCommand jCmd = new SqlCommand(jString, myConnection);
                myConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rr = jCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rr.Read())
                    {
                        CustAcc accounts = new CustAcc();
                        custEmail = rr["custEmail"].ToString();
                        custPassword = rr["custPassword"].ToString();
                        acc.Add(accounts);
                    }
                    myConnection.Close();
                }
            }
            return acc;
        }
```

CustAcc.cs

```
public class CustAcc
    { 
        public string custFullName { get; set; }
        public string custPreferredName { get; set; }
        public string custPassword { get; set; }
        public string custEmail { get; set; }
        public string custPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }


        public CustAcc(string custName, string custFullName, string custPreferredName, string custPassword, string custEmail, string custPhoneNumber)
        {
            this.custFullName = custFullName;
            this.custPreferredName = custPreferredName;
            this.custPassword = custPassword;
            this.custEmail = custEmail;
            this.custPhoneNumber = custPhoneNumber;
        }

        public CustAcc()
        {
            this.custEmail = custEmail;
            this.custPassword = custPassword;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error and where does it occur, your problem can be solved much faster if you give a clean and concise question

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre It gave me this error "Cannot implicitly convert type " 'System.Collection.GenericList<website.Model.CustAcc>' to 'System.Collection.GenericList<WS.CustAcc>' "

Answer (score 0):

Move your Model classes to their own assembly called Model and reference the assembly in both the WS and website assemblies.

You will also need to setup the Service reference in your website to look for the Service types in the Model assembly (it's an option in the Add Service Reference wizard).

Comment: Sorry I do not get what you mean? do you have any references